# Is there some kind of lower bound for estimation error of the estimation of (near) low-rank matrices in high-dimension?

Tags: matrices, st.statistics

I'm reading S.Negahban and M.J.Wainright's paper, ESTIMATION OF (NEAR) LOW-RANK MATRICES WITH NOISE AND HIGH-DIMENSIONAL SCALING. In the paper, they give a upper bound for estimation error of the estimation in the trace regression model with nuclear norm penalty under the condition of RSC, restricted strong convexity.

But they didn't give a lower bound of the estimation error of the estimation. So I wonder is there any research for any kind of the lower bound?

I know in A.ROHDE and A.B.TSYBAKOV's paper,ESTIMATION OF HIGH-DIMENSIONAL LOW-RANK MATRICES, they give a lower bound for the estimation, in some kind of min-max principle under the condition of RIP, restricted isometry condition. So are there similar results if we under different condition?

THANKS!